# best practice of compare a map of metadata with an object?

Tags: java

I have a map of metadata and Expression class:

```
Map<String , Object> metaDate;

public class Expression{
   private List<UserCondition> conditions;
   private LogicalOperationEnum;   // and , or
   getters/stters...
}

public classUserCondition{
   private String fieldName;
   private MathOperationEnum operation;   // > , < , >=  , <= , =
   private Object value;
   getters/setters...
}
```

Now I hav a method this method in my businessService class:

```
private boolean evaluate(Map<String, Object> userMetaData, Expression expression) {
    if (expression.getLogicalOperation() == LogicalOperationEnum.and) {
        for (UserCondition c : expression.getConditions()) {
            if (c.getOperation().getName() == ">" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) <= 0) {
                return false;
            } else if (c.getOperation().getName() == "<" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) >= 0) {
                return false;
            } else if (c.getOperation().getName() == "<=" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) > 0) {
                return false;
            } else if (c.getOperation().getName() == ">=" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) < 0) {
                return false;
            } else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else if (expression.getLogicalOperation() == LogicalOperationEnum.or) {
        for (UserCondition c : expression.getConditions()) {
            if (c.getOperation().getName() == ">" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) > 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (c.getOperation().getName() == "<" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) < 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (c.getOperation().getName() == "<=" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) <= 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (c.getOperation().getName() == ">=" && String.valueOf(userMetaData.get(c.getField())).compareTo(String.valueOf(c.getValue())) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now i think that this method can implement better than , but i don't know how can i do that?

Comment: I doubt whether comparing strings with `==` is what you want to do.  You also want `return true;` on the line above the `else if`.

Comment: in 'and' operation if one of that conditions be false, all of conditions is false and in 'or' operation if one of that conditions be true , all of conditions is true.

Comment: Yes, but your code as you've written it can't return `true` in the `AND` case.

Comment: I edit that , is correct now??

Comment: No it's not. You should have put the `return true;` where I specified in my first comment.

Comment: _...Now, I think that this method can be implemented better..._ It would be helpful if you could state your question a bit more specific. What do you think is not "good enough" with your current implementation? And what aspect of your current code should improve how? E.g. code-readability, code testability, performance, correctness, ...?